# Why can't bcrypt find 'checkpw'

Tags: python, bcrypt

I'm writing a program with Python. It has a login and I want to use bcrypt but it's not working.
Instead, it shows the following error message:

> AttributeError: type object 'bcrypt' has no attribute 'checkpw'. Did you mean: 'checksum'?

It also showed an error message when I used `bcrypt.hashpw` instead of `bcrypt.hash`. So I changed that.

Here is my code:

```
    import bcrypt

    db.base.metadata.create_all(db.engine)
    my_session = Session(bind=engine)


    def login():
        #password = getpass("Please enter your password: ").strip()
        password = pwinput.pwinput(mask='*')
        hashed_password = bcrypt.hash(password.encode('utf-8'))
        check_user_exists(username, password, hashed_password)


    def check_user_exists(username, password, hashed_password):
        db_user = my_session.query(User).filter_by(username=username).first()
        if db_user is None:
            user = User(username=username, password=hashed_password)
            my_session.add(user)
            my_session.commit()
            print("A new User " + username + " has been registered")
        else:
            if not bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf-8'), hashed_password):
                print("Wrong password")
                login()
        print("successful login")
```

I reinstalled bcrypt, I reinstalled anaconda3, I checked if the folder was named bcrypt.py

Comment: Did you create a file named `bcrypt`? Maybe you aren't importing what you think you are importing.

Comment: Check if your bcrypt is coming from passlib.hash. That is a different bcrypt and has "hash" interface. The https://pypi.org/project/bcrypt/ library is different and has "hashpw" and "checkpw" interface.

Comment: With that import `bcrypt` is never going to be a `type`. There seems to be something missing you did not show us.

Comment: Amazing! bcrypt came from passlib. now it's working:) Thank you!